# Second derivative of Brownian motion?

Tags: calculus, probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

My question is, we give a meaning to the following expression:
$$dX(t) = \mu(t,X(t))dt + \sigma(t,X(t))dW(t), \ \ X(0)=x.$$
where $W$ is a Wiener process.

This equation can be thought as
$$\frac{dX(t)}{dt} = \mu(t,X(t)) + \sigma(t,X(t))\frac{dW(t)}{dt}, \ \ X(0)=x.$$

Now, if I wanted to differentiate again in an ODE I would write something like:

$$\frac{d^2X(t)}{dt^2} = \mu'(t,X(t)) + \sigma'(t,X(t))\frac{d^2W(t)}{dt^2}, \ \ X(0)=x.$$
But, my question is, can we do this in Stochastic ODE's? Does the term $\frac{d^2W(t)}{dt^2}$ have a meaning? What would one do in this case? Any idea, literature, reference?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write 
$$dX(t) = \mu(t,X(t))dt + \sigma(t,X(t))dW(t), \ \ X(0)=x.$$
this is an 'abuse of notation' and should be read as the equation

$$X(t)-x = \int_0^T\mu(t,X(t))dt + \int_0^T\sigma(t,X(t))dW(t)\qquad t\geq0.$$

This equation can't be solved pathwise since it would have no meaning. It has a more complex structure due to the stochastic integral $\int_0^T\sigma(t,X(t))dW(t)$ which is not differentiable in $T$.

Comment: Sure.. I see it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: "This equation can't be solved pathwise since it would have no meaning" This is unrelated to the question asked and is in fact false: for tons of functions $(\mu,\sigma)$, the SDE can very much be solved pathwise.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is filtering first the Wiener process by a compactly supported  $C^k$ function (hence it is a low-pass filter), then differentiating at most $k+1$ times.