# An evolution equation for the logarithmic derivative of geometric Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Consider the SDE
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathop{dS_t}=S_t\left(r\mathop{dt}+\sigma(t,S_t)\mathop{dW_t}\right),
\end{equation}

Suppose that $\int_0^{t} X_s\mathop{dW_s}=\ln S_t-\ln S_0$ and $\mathop{dX_t}=a_t\mathop{dt}+b_t\mathop{dW_t}$. Then
\begin{equation}
X_s=X_0+\int_0^{s} a_u\mathop{du}+\int_0^{s} b_u\mathop{dW_u},
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{t} X_s\mathop{dW_s}=\int_0^{t} X_0 \mathop{dW_s} + \int_0^{t}\int_0^{s} a_u\mathop{du}\mathop{dW_s}+\int_0^{t}\int_0^{s} b_u\mathop{dW_u}\mathop{dW_s}.
\end{equation}
Applying Itô's lemma to $(1)$ and letting $\sigma_t:=\sigma(t,S_t)$ for convenience,
\begin{equation}
\ln S_t=\ln S_0+\int_0^{t}\left(r-\frac{\sigma_s^2}{2}\right)\mathop{ds}+\int_0^{t}\sigma_s\mathop{dW_s}.
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
rt-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t}\sigma_s^2\mathop{ds}+\int_0^{t}\sigma_s\mathop{dW_s}=X_0 W_t + \int_0^{t}\int_0^{s} a_u\mathop{du}\mathop{dW_s}+\int_0^{t}\int_0^{s} b_u\mathop{dW_u}\mathop{dW_s}.
\end{equation}
Is there any way to solve for $a_t$ and $b_t$ in terms of $\sigma_t$ and $r$? My intention here is to describe the evolution of the derivative of returns $d(\ln S_t)$ with respect to Brownian motion $\mathop{dW_t}$ (since the time derivative is undefined). I would expect that this implicitly involves taking the second derivative of $S_t$ w.r.t. $\mathop{dW_t}$ and I am unsure of whether this makes sense rigorously.

Comment: You could (in a non-rigorous way) say that I'm trying to find an equation for $d^2(\ln S_t)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419307/second-derivative-of-brownian-motion) for the general idea.

Comment: The first equation for $X$ is likely not satisfiable, as that imply that $\ln(S)$ is a martingale, which is not generally the case.